# Is there a function to get a specific value in a column associated to other values in other columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have just started using pandas dataframes and I wanted to know if there is a way to get a value in column, by knowing values of different columns?

Let's suppose a dataframe (df), with the following columns. In the case that I have one value from 'u' and 'v' example `u = 123` and `v = 962`.

Is there a way to get value in column B corresponding to thoses values ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[30, 2, 12, 4, 32, 33, 69],
                   'B':['valx', 'valy', 'valz', 'val45', 'val78', 'val516', 'val123'],
                   'C':['Steak', 'Lamb', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Cheese', 'Melon', 'Beans'],
                   'D':[165, 70, 120, 80, 180, 172, 150],
                   'u':[147,258,369,123,893,123,879],
                   'v':[123,456,789,741,852,963,369]
                   },
                  index=['123', '456', '483', '861', '789', '963', '753'])
```

```
       A       B        C       D        u   v

123    30     valx     165     Steak    147 123
456    2      valy     70      Lamb     258 456
483    12     valz     120     Mango    369 789
861    4      val45    80      Apple    123 741
789    32     val78    180     Cheese   893 852
963    33     val516   172     Melon    123 963
753    69     val12    150     Beans    879 369
```

Currently to solve this problem I do the following code, I am sur that there is prefered way ... :-/

```
extrait = df[(df['u'] == 123 ) & (df['v'] == 962)]
Val_in_B = extrait['B'][0]
Val_in_B
>>>  val516
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less. In fact, as you select the row with a condition, you might have 0, 1, or many values. That is the reason why the selection of one single column will give you a series.

But you can do one single extraction that way:

```
df.loc[(df.u==123)&(df.v==963), 'B']
```

It then only make sense to take the first element if you are sure that the search will return exactly one value.

Comment: I spent a day seecking that solution, you just saved my life !!  <3